# C# mongo $push error

Tags: c#, mongodb

I has the following C# codes in retrieving mongo data:

```
 var match = new BsonDocument
             {
                { "$match",
                    new BsonDocument { { "Country", paramsEntity.Country },
                                       { "Staff_ID", String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.StaffID) ? "$Staff_ID" : paramsEntity.StaffID },
                                       { "WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year.$", paramsEntity.Year == null ? "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year.$" : paramsEntity.Year.ToString() },
                                       { "WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month.$", paramsEntity.Month == null ? "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month.$" : paramsEntity.Month.ToString() },
                                     }
                }
            };

            var unwind = new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction");

            var group = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$group",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "_id", new BsonDocument { { "Country","$Country" },
                                                        { "Staff_ID", "$Staff_ID" },
                                                        { "Trans_Year", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year" },
                                                        { "Trans_Month", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month" }
                                                      }
                            }, 
                { "$push",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "CustPastAnswers", new BsonDocument { { "SurveyComment", "$WeCare.CustPastAnswers.SurveyComment" } } }
                        }
                },
                { "HH", new BsonDocument { { "$sum", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.HH" } } } }
              }
            };

            var project = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$project",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"_id", 0},
                            {"Staff_ID", "$_id.Staff_ID"},
                            { "CustSatisfaction", new BsonDocument { { "Trans_Year", "$_id.Trans_Year" },
                                                                     { "Trans_Month", "$_id.Trans_Month" },
                                                                     { "HH", 1 },
                                                                   } },
                            { "CustPastAnswers", new BsonDocument { { "SurveyComment", "$SurveyComment" } } },

                        }
                }
            };

            var pipeline = new[] { match, unwind, group, project };
            var result = mongoDB.Consultant.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
            var b = result.Select(c => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MongoConsultantResult>(c)).ToList();
```

I am having error at the $push there. Actually I am trying to retrieve all CustPastAnswers for the staff without any grouping. Is there any better way to do it?

The following my mongo query and it's working fine:

```
    db.getCollection('Consultant').aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction"} // important step!
    ,{$group: {_id: {Country: "$Country",
               Staff_ID: "$Staff_ID",
               Trans_Year: "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year",
               Trans_Month: "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month"},
               CustPastAnswers:{$push: {
                   SurveyComment:"$WeCare.CustPastAnswers.SurveyComment"
              }},
      HH: {$sum: "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.HH"}}}
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your mongo query, "group" part of the code should be like this.

```
    var group = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "$group",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "_id", new BsonDocument { { "Country","$Country" },
                                                { "Staff_ID", "$Staff_ID" },
                                                { "Trans_Year", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Year" },
                                                { "Trans_Month", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.Trans_Month" }
                                              }
                    },
                    { "CustPastAnswers", new BsonDocument { { "$push",
                                                            new BsonDocument { { "SurveyComment", "$WeCare.CustPastAnswers.SurveyComment" } } 
                                                            }
                                                          }                            
                    },
                    { "HH", new BsonDocument { { "$sum", "$WeCare.CustSatisfaction.HH" } }
                    }
                }
         }
     };
```